# How do I improve battery life for my 2017 mac air (intel)?

Tags: battery, charging

I have a mac air 2017 bought in Jan 2020. I have replaced the battery in August 2022 when it had a cycle count close to 1200+, a charge capacity left of ~5000mah, and have used Catalina till this point. Currently, the new battery has a cycle count of 312 and a charge capacity of 6611mah (almost 300-400mah reduction). I think I heard somewhere new OS does better charge management. Since I installed Monterey in 2022 October (Ventura is not available for this mac model), from the cycle count here, it doesn't seem to be working well. I have gone through several post here for recommendation and seen most saying not to worry about the count. But the way it is going, I may need to replace next time even before 2years of use. So, I am wondering if anyone has any recommendations to improve battery life other than the ones listed here: https://www.apple.com/batteries/maximizing-performance/

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How heavily are you using your MBA? August 22 was six months ago: that suggests you are doing two complete charge cycles a day. What do you use your MBA to do?

Comment: @benwiggy I use it about 12hrs daily with two chrome profiles (personal, academic)/ combined avg. 10 tabs (always open), zoom (30-60mins), slack (always open), visual studio (1hrs), mendeley (2-3hrs). In chrome, I will at least have one overleaf window, one youtube, one google doc, and one gmail tab open.  In the background, I have google drive syncing. From this, I am getting 6hrs per cycle.  Config-wise, I have 8GB ram and 40GB ssd free out of 128GB. Now I am wondering if I am  my RAM is the issue, e.g. if there is too many read/writes.

Comment: That's very heavy use for an 'Air', which is intended to be a light-to-moderate use machine. With that workload, then I don't think you can make any significant improvement to the life of the battery, apart from: don't use Chrome; and put the Mac down and enjoy life every now and then. ;-)

Comment: @benwiggy I see. Thanks. I will get a laptop (pro) from work this fall. Hopefully, this one will be able to breath some air then.

Comment: The M-series laptops have extraordinary battery life. (Chrome notwithstanding.) ;-)